# inserting data from another table and data from textbox and checkbox to create a new record

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, insert, textbox

I have to insert from table 1 into table 2 the values of username, name, lastname, roomnum and dormID.

I have to insert into table 2 the current date of today(it changes everyday), comments(the user wishes to enter- this is a textbox) and the attendance(present, absent, late)(these are the checkboxes).

When trying to click on the submit button the only thing that inserts into the database is the records that I am pulling from table1 into table 2.

When i try to incorporate to also insert the date, latecomments(textbox), and the attendance(checkboxes) it does not store any record.

This are the inserts:

```
$checkbox1 = $_POST['chk1'];
$latecomment=trim($_POST['latecomment']);
$d=strtotime("today");//todays date
$day=date("Y-m-d", $d);//date format


if($_POST["Submit"]=="Submit"){

    for ($i=0; $i < sizeof ($checkbox1); $i++){
        $query="Insert into dailyattendance (attendance) VALUES ('".$checkbox1[$i]."')";
        mysql_query($query);
        $daily=mysql_query("INSERT INTO dailyattendance(username, name, lastname, roomnum, dormID) SELECT user.username, user.name, user.lastname, user.roomnum, user.dormID FROM user WHERE user.role='Student'" ); 
        $otherinfo=mysql_query("INSERT INTO daily attendance set  date='".$day."', latecomment='".$latecomment."' WHERE dailyid=''");   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. There's a blank in your table name (in your given code):

   INSERT INTO daily attendance
2. There's a WHERE clause in your INSERT statement and you are using UPDATE syntax with SET:

   INSERT INTO daily attendance set  date='".$day."', latecomment='".$latecomment."' WHERE dailyid=''");
3. Question: Is there a column named "attendance" in your table?
4. You should use only one INSERT statement if you want to add one row with all columns.

---

To clearify it a bit here is a code example you could start with. The SELECT on user is once before the loop because it seems to be same data all the time. You should add a function to escape strings before using them in the SQL statement to avoid errors when quotes are in it. Have a look at PHP or SQL error messages if something went wrong.

```
if($_POST["Submit"]=="Submit"){
    $sql = "SELECT username, name, lastname, roomnum, dormID FROM user WHERE user.role='Student'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $student = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    for($i=0; $i < sizeof ($checkbox1); $i++){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO dailyattendance (username, name, lastname, roomnum, dormID, attendance, date, latecomment)";
        $sql.= " VALUES ('".$student["username"]."', '".$student["name"]."', '".$student["lastname"]."', '".$student["roomnum"]."', '".$student["dormID"]."'";
        $sql.= ", '".$checkbox1[$i]."', now(), '".$latecomment."')";
        mysql_query($sql); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Theres no blank in the table. its called dailyattendance all together.
Yes there is a column named attendance, in that column it is ENUM and the only options are "present" "absent" "late".

I was not sure how to store all the information. Currently the only information that stores into the dailyattendance table is the information from table users.

Comment: so how would i be able to verify the checkboxes if there is a total of 3 options. Checkbox present, checkbox absent, checkbox late